# Expand the list of sites in the Close Vote reason "Belongs on another site"on the main site

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I suggest expanding the list of sites in the Close Vote reason *Belongs on another site* on the main site. That will at least give the 'offenders' more information than Blatantly off-topic (which they would have to read the tour for to understand why - and we know how much people read).

It would still require discipline from close-voters to distinguish questions that would be off-topic 'over there' as well (a bad question is a bad question).

Comment: Good idea. Stackoverflow, superuser, ubuntu, hardwarerec come to mind.

Comment: All of those!! Plus Unix & Linux, and, occasionally, Internet of Things, although I am not sure if we should that. Also, it is low traffic.