# Closing with 3 votes: Do we want that experiment?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, vote-to-close

Stack Overflow is running an experiment where 3 close votes are enough to close a question:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388313/experiment-closing-and-reopening-happens-at-3-votes

Should we ask for the same experiment on Software Recommendations?

Comment: What do you think is a good goal for the size of the Close Votes review queue?

Comment: I would say that ideally it should reach zero about once every week or so (not sure if realistic). Maybe https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2862/would-single-vote-closure-be-helpful-here is better for us actually, but I would gladly accept any of these experiments.

Comment: Definitely. Seeing how many users with sufficient rep we have at all, and how many VTC they throw, 5 isn't achieving a thing. 3 will already be hard enough. Some days it seems to me as if 90% of all closures go on me…

Comment: PS: If a site like SO needs such an experiment, that seems like a bad sign…

Comment: Hardware Recommendations ran another experiment where everyone with closing privileges was granted binding close votes.

Comment: @gparyani: Indeed! I believe this is the topic of https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2862/would-single-vote-closure-be-helpful-here :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the size of our review queues, this is a good idea.

Yes, let's ask for the same experiment on Software Recommendations SE.

If lowering the threshold to 3 is not sufficient, we can then experiment with 2 or even 1.

Comment: There are sooooo many questions coming in that can be closed without any doubt, that even 3 is high. But yes, 1 might be risky....

Comment: I agree with the answer. A resounding yes, ***but*** I would like to expand the closure reason "belongs on another site" to include - definitely S.O, probably SuperUser too. We also get some misplaced Android questions, but I am not sure where we should draw the line (I see the occasional Internet of Things question, but probably not enough to justify adding it as a closure reason).  Btw, if I am certain of the site where a questions belongs, should I flag it for a mod to migrate, rather than voting to close?

Comment: @mawg https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2851/expand-the-list-of-sites-in-the-close-vote-reason-belongs-on-another-siteon-th

Answer (score 2):

Some of you may have noticed the Meta Stack Exchange post - [Testing three-vote close and reopen on 13 network sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364007/testing-three-vote-close-and-reopen-on-13-network-sites) (it's linked in the featured on meta sidebar) - we've finally got this project under way and Software Recs is one of the sites we'll be running the test on.

Starting tomorrow, I'll be changing the site setting and closing and reopening will require only three votes. This test will run for 45 days and will be turned back to five votes to close and reopen while I review the data from the 13 sites. After we've seen the impact, I'll be posting results and, if there aren't negative impacts, we will change the setting to three permanently.

A few weeks into this, I'll be posting a question here on meta to ask for your thoughts about this change, so you will have an opportunity to discuss the impact.

Thank you so much for your patience while we got this prioritized and scheduled. There's a lot more information in the MSE post, so please review it.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is a very very fast stackexchange, while Softwarerecs is quite slow. Instead of automatically closing questions we should be asking the OP to review and revise it. Closing questions would just inhibit this site's traffic, and besides, not many questions are low quality anyways.