# Why is this site having such a low answered rate?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, migration, unanswered-questions

Since many off-topic questions on other SE sites are suggested to migrate to this site (At least 2/3 of my off-topic questions are), I suppose this site should have a big answer rate.

But the fact is just the opposite.

I saw the community summary in Stack Exchange and chose "sort by answer rate", then it was a huge surprise to me that Software Recommendations hit the **lowest** among all these nearly 100 sites. The answer rate is 46%, even lower than half.

Most of the communities are above 70%, just a few are lower than 70% answer rate. But this 46% really surprised me - Why is it **that** low?

46% answered rate in this site (Software Recommendations) seems to be implying people that they are not likely to get their questions solved (or at least, solved soon) on this site compared to the other SE sites.

Is this a result of "Askers are too more than Answerers", or "It's hard to find a software that fits"? Or I have some misunderstandings about the answer rate? Suggestions and critics to me are welcomed.

Comment: The percentage of unanswered questions would be even higher if Stack Exchange didn't automatically delete many questions... See [Should we disable the Roomba?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2459/903) and [Make sure your questions don't get deleted silently: beware of Roomba!](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1116/903). Deletion of good user content definitely kills my motivation to participate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are many questions coming in, therefore they are not seen (enough) before they disappear out of sight. It's not as bad as on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [SU](https://superuser.com/), but substantial.
2. This number has [increased a lot since the question wizard on Stack Overflow got implemented](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/recent-proliferation-of-how-to-code-questions-superuser-questions), *and* a lot of those redirected from thye wizard are off-topic - they are essentially off-loading garbage to other SE sites. [Handling the off topic questions already takes a lot of effort](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/closing-with-3-votes-do-we-want-that-experiment).
3. Answering software requests may not be very sexy.
4. There is a *lot* of different software, and for different OSes as well.

Comment: another reason from just going through the first posts review queue is it seems like theres quite a few near-duplicates due to people not searching for a solution first before posting