# Would single-vote closure be helpful here?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

I recently noticed [this](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/655/13013) on Hardware Recommendations:

> Testing single-vote closure on Hardware Recs

As far as I am concerned, we Software Recommendations [is facing a similar problem](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2809/32168) since long ago (more precisely, the Ask Question Wizard on Stack Overflow).

Does the SoftwareRecs community think that a similar mechanism would help ease the ache?

Comment: The situation is certainly almost the same – only one slight difference: HW is still in Beta, we're not. But I welcome the discussion – so thanks for bringing it up! Let me link another related Meta-Q here to stick things together: [Let's design our own Ask Question Wizard guide](/q/2853/185) (that idea/task was mentioned on HW as well).

Answer (score 3):

This would be very welcome here!

There are always a hundred questions in review, and the volume of incoming off-topic questions is such that our community is not able to reduce the backlog despite doing its best.

It leaves the 3 moderators alone to do all of the work of closing questions, which is not their primary role, and causes burnout.

Single-vote close would give our very skilled power-users the ability to help with moderation much more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

On very fast sites such as Stackoverflow, this feature would be useful because so many questions are low quality. However, on Softwarerecs not many questions are posted each day. Instead of automatically closing questions we should be asking the OP to review and revise it. Closing questions would just inhibit this site's traffic, and besides, not many questions are low quality anyways.